# SQL identity with character autogenerated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below table: Using SQL Server

```
create table PoojaDetails
(
    PoojaDetailsID int identity constraint pk_PoojaDetailsID Primary Key, 
    ReceiptNo AS 'PB' + '/' + datepart(yy,getdate()) + '/' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(PoojaDetailsID AS VARCHAR(10)), 6) PERSISTED,
    ReceiptDate datetime not null constraint df_ReceiptDate default getdate(),
    FirstName varchar(100) not null,
    LastName varchar(100) not null,
    TelNo bigint
)
```

When i execute the query: Computed column 'ReceiptNo' in table 'PoojaDetails' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

I would like to have the ReceiptNo as : PB/year/no
for e.g; PB/13/213433

Any ideas??? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try it,

```
create table PoojaDetails
(
    PoojaDetailsID int identity constraint pk_PoojaDetailsID  Primary Key, 
    ReceiptNo  AS 'PB' + '/' + cast(datepart(yy,getdate()) as varchar(25)) + '/' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(PoojaDetailsID AS VARCHAR(10)), 6) ,
    ReceiptDate datetime not null constraint df_ReceiptDate default getdate(),
    FirstName varchar(100) not null,
    LastName varchar(100) not null,
    TelNo bigint
)
```

Comment: No, it cannot be `persisted` whilst that call to `getdate()` is in there.

Answer (score 1):

If you can rely on `ReceiptDate` always being populated by its default constraint and never changing, then you can use it instead of `getdate()` in your computed column:

```
create table PoojaDetails
(
    PoojaDetailsID int identity constraint pk_PoojaDetailsID Primary Key, 
    ReceiptNo AS 'PB' + '/' + CONVERT(varchar(5),datepart(yy,ReceiptDate)) + '/' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(PoojaDetailsID AS VARCHAR(10)), 6) PERSISTED,
    ReceiptDate datetime not null constraint df_ReceiptDate default getdate(),
    FirstName varchar(100) not null,
    LastName varchar(100) not null,
    TelNo bigint
)
```

Comment: Dear Damien_The_Unbeliever This query is begin Create Successfully But when we execute select query it is giving error

Comment: It is giving it---- Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'PB/' to data type int.